US/Canadian Road Movie about a rock/Indie band
In this movie a band is on tour, the Band goes on ahead in the tour bus and the lead singer goes off on his own to 'find himself' i,e stare at lakes, clouds, tumbleweeds. At some point he hooks up with a journalist and gets a lift. At another point he upsets a psycho who then follows him.  I think the band only plays at the finale but they are a short haired indie rock band similar to Fugazi or a more edgy version of REM.
It's a real slow burner with very little dialogue, it has a similar feel to 'Static' the god is in the TV movie or 'Paris Texas'. It was in English but I would guess Canadian or maybe Australia as it had no real Hollywood action scenes a real low budget student type thing. 
I think I watched it pre 2000 so by the look of it it would have been mid 90s.
I know exactly how it ends but don't want to give spoilers.

This time the google search put this at the top..... http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098209/
I'm pretty sure this one fits the bill, thanks anyway.
